# create a list of dictionaries with randomised elements from two lists - python

Tags: python, list, random, dictionary

Is there a way in python to perform randomization between two lists within a list and have a dictionary returned?

For example, from:

```
[[1,2,3,4], ['a','b','c','d']]
```

to:

```
[{3:'a'}, {1:'d'}, {2:'c'}, {4:'b'}]
```

What's the best way to achieve this? Using a list comprehension? My two lists are actually very large, so I'm wondering whether there's a more efficient alternative.

Comment: Do you really want a list of singleton dictionaries, as your code suggests, or do you want a single dicitonary, as your text suggests?  The former data structure seems rather pointless to me.

Comment: Do you really want a list of single-item dicts (which is the output you've asked for), or a single dict like `{1: 'd', 2: 'a', 3: 'c', 4: 'b'}`?

Comment: I want the list showed in the output because that's how an external program expects the list to be structured.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
import random
keys, values = [[1,2,3,4], ['a','b','c','d']]
random.shuffle(values)
result =  [{k:v} for k, v in zip(keys, values)]
```

produces a list such as:

```
In [7]: result
Out[7]: [{1: 'd'}, {2: 'b'}, {3: 'c'}, {4: 'a'}]
```

A more memory-efficient alternative would be to use an iterator:

```
import itertools as IT
result = ({k:v} for k, v in IT.izip(keys, values))
```

The larger question is why you would want a sequence of tiny dicts. Wouldn't it be more useful to have one dict, such as the one produced by Steven Rumbalski's answer?

Or, if you really do just want a randomized pairing, perhaps an iterator of tuples would suffice:

```
result = IT.izip(keys, values)
```

Comment: But how can I access the dictionaries in the list then?

Comment: You can loop through the items with `for dct in result`.

Answer (score 2):

This creates a single dictionary rather than a list of single item dictionaries as your question requests.  If you really want that, use [unutbu's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18152193/1322401).

```
import random

a = [1,2,3,4]
b = ['a','b','c','d']

random.shuffle(a)
result = dict(zip(a, b))
```

If you cannot mutate your source lists:

```
dx = range(len(a))
random.shuffle(dx)
dict(zip((a[i] for i in dx), b))
```

Comment: This will result in a dict, not a list of dictionaries.  (The OP's desired structure is kind of strange, so I was fooled too.)

Comment: @DSM:  I missed that.  I'll leave it as is because unutbu refers to it in his answer.